# Symfony 2.8 Services issue

Tags: php, symfony-2.8

Since the last 4 hours I'm trying to understand the logic of Symfony 2 services and how they integrate in the application...

Basically I'm trying to set my EntityManager via a service and use it in a controller

I have the following structure

```
Bundle1/Controller/Bundle1Controller.php
Bundle1/Services/EntityService.php
Bundle2/Controller/Bundle2Controller.php
Bundle3/Controller/Bundle3Controller.php
....
```

I'm trying to make a REST API with different entry points, that's why I use multiple bundles `bundle2,bundle3....`

The logic is the following:

- A POST is fired to Bundle2/Controller/Bundle2Controller.php
- Bundle2Controller.php instances a new() Bundle1Controller.php
- Inside Bundle1Controller I want to access a service `entity_service` in order to get my EntityManager

I have 2 cases in which I manage to land...

1. In `Bundle1/Controller/Bundle1Controller` if I try `$this->container` or `$this->get('entity_service')` I get a `null` everytime
2. If I set the container in `Bundle2/Controller/Bundle2Controller` and try `$this->get('entity_service')` I get `You have requested a non-existent service "entity_service"`

I will place all the code below

**Bundle1/Controller/Bundle1Controller**

```
<?php

namespace Bundle1\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use EntityBundle\Entity\TestEntity;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;

class Bundle1Controller extends Controller
{

    /**
     * @param $response
     * @return array
     */
    public function verifyWebHookRespone($response){

        $em = $this->get('entity_service')->getEm();

        $array = json_decode($response);

        $mapping = $em->getRepository('EntityBundle:TestEntity')
               ->findBy(["phone" => $array['usernumber']]);

        return $mapping;

    }
}
```

**Bundle2/Controller/Bundle2Controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace Bundle2\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Bundle1\Controller\Bundle1Controller;

class Bundle2Controller extends Controller
{

    public function webhookAction(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->request->get('messages');

        $model = new Bundle1Controller();
        $responseMessage = $model->verifyWebHookRespone($data);

        return new Response($responseMessage, Response::HTTP_CREATED, ['X-My-Header' => 'My Value']);

    }
}
```

**Bundle1/Services/EntityService.php**

```
<?php

namespace EntityBundle\Services;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container;

class EntityService
{
    protected $em;
    private $container;


    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Container $container)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */

    public function getEm()
    {
        return $this->em;
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:    
entity_service:
        class: Bundle1\Services\EntityService
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" , "@service_container"   ]
```

Can anyone please help me with something regarding this issue?
How can I register a service and call it from anywhere no matter the bundle or another service?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should check where your services.yml is located and whether it is imported in the config.yml
2. You can't just instantiate a controller and expect it to work, you need to set the container.
3. But you can call EntityManager without needing any other service by using;

`$this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');`

I can't understand your structure or what you are trying to achieve, but those are the options to go about if you want to keep this structure.